# Linux Mint taskbar suddenly disappeared and all application closed

Tags: linux-mint

After i waited for couple minutes the screen turn black, then it shows sda1 errors

This happened frequently, everytime i open for like half an hour this happened and i force to restart and everything work like normal again

Answer (score 0):

If it is a portable/laptop, PC check if it does not overheat, this can explain the power-off.

But the sdax is the hard disk, so it can be a problem with the drive.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response, but can you tell me how to fix this problem? I am using a PC. I don't know if it overheated, but the fan in the CPU sounds quite loud.

Comment: First get information about show the CPU temp. Nirlally 'sensors' in CLI  or add widget in control panel.You have to check the fan who cool the CPU, and the heat transfer medium.

Comment: "No sensors found!
" after run "sensors -u" any ideas how to fix this?